# Does IntegrateChangeVariables work with improper integrals?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Trying a new command of version 13.1 `IntegrateChangeVariables`, I obtain

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][1/x^2, {x, 1, Infinity}], t, t == 1/x]
```

> `Inactive[Integrate][-1, {t, 0, 1}]`

```
Activate[Inactive[Integrate][-1, {t, 0, 1}], Unevaluated[Integrate]]
```

> `-1`

which is not correct. The documentation to `IntegrateChangeVariables` says nothing about improper integrals. However,

```
Inactive[Integrate][Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity,  Infinity}];
IntegrateChangeVariables[%, {r, \[Theta]}, "Cartesian" -> "Polar"];
Activate[%]
```

works well, resulting in `Pi`. So does `IntegrateChangeVariables` work with improper integrals?

Comment: `IntegrateChangeVariables` is still marked as EXPERIMENTAL in the document, so I'm not too surprising to see this… I suggest reporting this to WRI.

Comment: I'd like to add that `IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][1/x^2, {x, 1, b}], t, 
 t == 1/x]` produces an incorrect result `ConditionalExpression[Inactive[Integrate][-1, {t, 1/b, 1}], b > 1]`.

Comment: `In[101]:= {Activate[
  IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][1/x^2, {x, 1, 10}], t, 
   t == 1/x]], Integrate[1/x^2, {x, 1, 10}]}
Out[101]= {-(9/10), 9/10}` This suggests the issue is not related to improper integrals.